# Angular8 - set variable in template

Tags: angular

I have a simple button which should set variable to a string constant. Variable is declared in component.ts and is accessible in template.

```
<button (click)="myVariable='all'" >Test</button>
```

In development mode all works fine, however using `ng build --prod --aot` ends with this error:

```
 Property 'all' does not exist on type 'GridComponent'
```

What I am doing wrong please?

EDIT:

I am well aware of posibility to change to a function call `setVariable('all')`
however, I wonder why is this working (number):

```
<button (click)="myVariable=1" >Test</button>
```

but this is not working (string)

```
<button (click)="myVariable='all'" >Test</button>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Use a function to set the variable value

Answer (score 1):

In your component:

```
public myVariable: string;

public setVariable(): string {
   this.myVariable = 'all';
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<button (click)="setVariable()">Test</button>
```

A better (more re-usable) way would be:

In your component:

```
public myVariable: string;

public setVariable(value: string): string {
   this.myVariable = value;
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<button (click)="setVariable('all')">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The prod build in angular expects the properties and methods declared in a component to be public in order to access them inside template.

So if we do not declare a property or a method in the component and try to use it in template, prod mode would throw error.

In addition, these properties and methods should be marked as public. If they are not, angular would still throw the error.

> EDIT

This is mainly because normal build uses JIT (Just In Time) compilation whereas prod mode uses AOT (Ahead Of Time) compilation strategy.

The JIT mode generates normal ES5 code and it doesn't have the concept of private fields and hence declaration of properties and their accessibility doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out what was the problem, shame on me. Expression `<button (click)="myVariable='all'" >Test</button>` is completely valid.

What causes the problem is [value] inside a radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="gridViewModeRadio" [value]="accounting" (change)="myVariable='accounting'" />
```

Working:

```
<input type="radio" name="gridViewModeRadio" [value]="'accounting'" (change)="myVariable='accounting'" />
```

Thanks for your effort!